# Smart Launcher - How do i change icon of an application on home screen

Tags: launcher

Smart launcher used to let me change icon of application shortcuts that are on home screen individually, by long pressing a shortcut.

Now it doesnt work anymore. How can i do that?

Comment: If the app does not allow it anymore, then you can't do it from that app. However, last time I checked, [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) did support it. I'm not sure that's why I've put it as a comment. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I love Smart launcher so i can't change. Thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay. You can still change the icon of a shortcut but the procedure changed with SL3. Long press on a bubble, then select "Edit Icon".